# MySQL query not working with nested select

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

The below code doesn't seem to work, I'm no expert with MySQL but this seems like it should work, any clues?

```
if($params['action'] == 'createTab'){
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("
        insert into
            dashboard_data
        (position, user_id)
            values
        (   
            (select
                max(position) + 1
            from
                dashboard_data
            where
                user_id=:userid
            ),
            :userid
        )
    ");
    $stmt->bindParam(':userid', $userId);
    $stmt->execute();
```

Comment: It looks like your nested select statement only produces one column and your insert expects 2 columns.   Use mysql command line or phpmyadmin and test your sql statements.  It's the easiest way to make sure they work.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
insert into dashboard_data (position, user_id)
select max(position) + 1, :userid 
from dashboard_data 
where user_id = :userid
```

Comment: The syntax is incorrect. You can't use `values` and the `select`

Comment: Ahh, so if i had removed the values keyword it should work? Is it just for string inputs?

Comment: No, look at the `:userid` variable. It is also somewhere else.